# My C# WPF webscraper returns error when more than one result is found

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on a WPF XAML application that scrapes certain websites for products. I have the search part working and it finds what I'm looking for. But as soon as there is more then 1 result I get a `System.InvalidoperationException`. I use a `ObservableCollection` to put the results into a `<ListBox>`.

Here is the search method:

```cs
private static ObservableCollection<EntryModel> _entries = new ObservableCollection<EntryModel>();

public static ObservableCollection<EntryModel> LoadCollectionData
{
    get { return _entries; }
    set { _entries = value; }
}

public static void PrehmSearchResults(string SearchQuery)
{
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

    try
    {
        string ZoekOpdracht = SearchQuery.Replace(" ", "+");
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://www.prehmshop.de/advanced_search_result.php?keywords=" + ZoekOpdracht);

        var title = doc.DocumentNode.CssSelect("div.header_cell > a").Single().InnerText;

        var links = doc.DocumentNode.CssSelect("a.product_link");
        var productLink = new List<string>();
        var productTitle = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in links)
        {
            if (item.Attributes["href"].Value.Contains(".html"))
            {
                productLink.Add(item.Attributes["href"].Value);
                productTitle.Add(title);
            }
        }

        var TitleAndLink = productLink.Zip(productTitle, (l, t) => new { productLink = l, productTitle = t });
        
        foreach (var nw in TitleAndLink)
        {
            var product = new List<EntryModel>();
            var adDetails = new EntryModel
            {
                Title = nw.productTitle,
                Link = nw.productLink
            };

            Debug.Print(adDetails.ToString());
            var ZoekOpdrachtInTitle = adDetails.Title.ToLower().Contains(ZoekOpdracht.ToLower());
            
            if (ZoekOpdrachtInTitle)
            {
                _entries.Add(adDetails);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you get the error on this line? `var title = doc.DocumentNode.CssSelect("div.header_cell > a").Single().InnerText;`. If so the `CssSelect()` returns more than 1 result and the `Single()` will fail at that point. It will also fail when it finds nothing. Is using the `FirstOrDefault()` an option? It will take the first of the results found. Take care, it will return `null` if nothing is found.

Comment: @PaulSinnema Just tried it, it works but it only shows the same result which is the first result on the website. I believe there is something wrong with my ```foreach``` loop. I might have to try and seperate methods to get the desired results. However I do hope it can be done within this method.

Comment: So there is a title for each link? A little bit more context would be nice.

Comment: @PaulSinnema Sorry, yes each link goes to a different product which all have a different title. That title has to correspond to the correct link which both will be printed in a ```<ListBox>```. The link is clickable and brings you to the page of the product. 

Here is a example search: https://www.prehmshop.de/advanced_search_result.php?keywords=polizei

Every product has a different title and a different link.

Comment: In that case you shouldn't use the `FirstOrDefault` but a `.ToList()` to get all the titles. Is the link part of the title? If so, itterate over the Titleslist and get the Title and Link to add to your collections.

Comment: @PaulSinnema No the link is a seperate entity. When I use a ```.ToList()```, how am I able to ```.Add``` the titles into ```var productTitle = new List<string>()``` then? Or will that be totally unnessecary?

Comment: How do you which link belongs to which title?

Comment: @PaulSinnema I found it, checked the html source again. The title is indeed part of the link. Check my solution below.

Comment: Good for you. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution without changing too much code. thanks for the help from @PaulSinnema.

The link is part of the title so I only had to change

```cs
var title = doc.DocumentNode.CssSelect("div.header_cell > a").ToList();
```

And I had to change the foreach loop:

```
foreach (var item in title)
{
    if (item.Attributes["href"].Value.Contains(".html"))
        {
            productLink.Add(item.Attributes["href"].Value);
            productTitle.Add(item.InnerText);
        }
}
```